# How to solve this functional equation $f(xf(y))+y+f(x)=f(x+f(y))+yf(x)$?

Tags: functional-equations

Find all function $f:\Bbb{R}→\Bbb{R}$ such that for all $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$
$$f(xf(y))+y+f(x)=f(x+f(y))+yf(x)~~~(1) $$
what I found is:
if we plug $x=0$ we find $$2f(0)+y=f(f(y))+yf(0)~~~ (2)$$
so either $f(0)=1$ which leads to $f(f(y))=2$ and if we plug $y=0$ in (1) we have $2f(x)=f(x+1)$
Hence $f(2)=2f(1)=4f(0)=4$ in the other hand $2=f(f(1))=f(2)=4 $ contradiction.
so $f(0)\ne 0 $,therefore, from (2) f is bijective.
We can plug $x=f(y)/(f(y)-1)$ in (1) we have that $$y+f(f(y)/(f(y)-1))=yf(f(y)/(f(y)-1))~~~ (3)$$
Suppose that $f(1)\ne1$ so if we plug $y=1$ in (3) we have $1=0$ which is a contradiction hence $f(1)=1$.
Besies, we plug $y=1$ in (2) gives us $f(0)=0$ so (2) becomes $f(f(y))=y$
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems that [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/) is especially [useful](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h205785p1132691) for functional equations. I also wonder what is the best practice for questions like this one: it is not a duplicate in the sense that it hasn't been posted on this site, but copy-pasting an answer from another site also doesn't feel like the right thing to do.

Comment: @WhatsUp I believe the correct thing to do is to copy-paste the answer, giving full credit (both the link and the user who came up with it). The reason is, many of us don't want to click on external links, and duplicating the solution here means that we don't have to worry about the other site going down or the solution being deleted (probably not an issue for AoPS). If you can't elaborate on the answer sufficiently that you think you deserve reputation for this, you can also just make your answer community wiki.

Comment: @TheoBendit I copied the answer there to a community wiki answer here. Was at first worried about having to retype all the LaTeX but thankfully their site support directly copying LaTeX commands.

Comment: Using what you've got, if you substitute $ f ( y ) $ for $ y $ in the original equation, you get the functional equation in the post [$g(x+y)+g(x)g(y)=g(xy)+g(x)+g(y)$ for all $x,y$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/481673/229831). The condition $ f \bigl ( f ( y ) \bigr ) = y $ rules out the constant solutions of that equation, and you get the identity function as the only solution of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Note: this answer is directly copied from [this thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h205785p1132691) on the site ArtOfProblemSolving, with minor formatting changes.

---

Suppose $ f(a) = f(b) = c$. Then $ f(xc) - f(x + c) = af(x) - a - f(x) = bf(x) - b - f(x)$. So as long as there exists an $ x$ such that $ f(x) \neq 1$, we get $ f$ injective. $ f(x) = 1$ for all $ x$ does not satisfy the original equation, so we can assume the existence of such an $ x$.

Put in $ x = 0$. We get $ f(f(y)) = y(1 - f(0)) + f(0)$. Suppose $ f(0) = 1$. Then put $ y = 0$ into that equation to get $ f(1) = 1$, contradicting $ f$ injective. Therefore $ f(0) \neq 1$ and $ f$ is bijective.

This means there exists a real $ c$ such that $ f(c) = 0$. Put in $ y = c$ to get $ f(0) + c = cf(x)$. The only way for this to be true if $ f$ is injective is for $ c = 0$. So $ f(0) = 0$. Now $ x = 0$ gives $ f(f(y)) = y$ for all reals $ y$.

Replace $ y$ in the given equation with $ f(y)$ to get the neater looking
$ f(xy) + f(x) + f(y) = f(x + y) + f(x)f(y)$.

Now for some substituting fun.
--- Put $ x = y = 2$ in to get $ f(2)^2 - 2f(2) = 0$. So $ f(2) = 2$ or $ f(2) = 0$. The latter contradicts $ f$ injective ($ f(2) \neq f(0)$), so $ f(2) = 2$.
--- Put $ x = y = 1$ in to get $ f(1)^2 - 3f(1) + 2 = 0$. So $ f(1) = 1$ or $ f(1) = 2$. The latter also contradicts $ f$ injective ($ f(1) \neq f(2)$), so $ f(1) = 1$.
--- Put $ x = 1$ in to get $ f(x) + 1 = f(x + 1)$. This also means $ f(x) = f(x - 1) + 1$. We also conclude $ f(n) = n$ for all integers $ n$. In particular $ f( - 1) = - 1$.
--- Put in $ x = - 1$ to get $ f( - x) + f(x) = f(x - 1) + 1 - f(x)$. The RHS is 0 by the previous line. So $ f( - x) = - f(x)$.
--- Put in $ y = - x$ to get $ f( - x^2) + f(x) + f( - x) = f(x)f( - x)$, or $ f(x^2) = f(x)^2$. There's actually only one thing important about this equation: $ f(x) > 0 \Leftrightarrow x > 0$, and because $ f$ is odd, $ f(x) < 0 \Leftrightarrow x < 0$.

We now show $ f(nx) = nf(x)$ for all positive integers $ n$; we do this by induction. Base case $ n = 1$ is trivial. If $ f(nx) = nf(x)$, then $ y = nx$ gives $ f(nx^2) + f(x) + f(nx) = f((n + 1)x) + f(x)f(nx)$, or $ f(x) + nf(x) = f((n + 1)x)$, or $ (n + 1)f(x) = f((n + 1)x)$ as wanted. Now by rewriting the identity as $ f(x) = nf(x/n)$ we see that identity actually holds for all rationals as well. Additionally, this gives $ f(x) = x$ for rationals since $ f(x) = xf(1) = x$.

Now suppose $ a$ is a rational, $ b$ is any real, and $ a < b$. Put in $ x = a, y = b - a$, and note $ y > 0$. We get $ f(a(b - a)) + f(a) + f(b - a) = f(b) + f(a)f(b - a)$, or $ a + f(b - a) = f(b)$. Recall from $ f(x^2) = f(x)^2$ that $ f(x) > 0 \Leftrightarrow x > 0$. As $ b - a > 0$, $ f(b - a) > 0$ and $ a = f(a) < f(b)$.

Finally if $ a$ is a rational, $ b$ is any real, and $ a > b$, then $ x = a, y = a - b$ gives similar stuff that leads to $ f(a) > f(b)$. By transitivity of $ >$, this shows that $ f$ is always increasing. As $ f$ is fixed on the rationals and the rationals are dense, this gives $ f(x) = x$ for all reals.